# How to update screenshots of an existing app on appstore?

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store

I've distributed/uploaded the IPA via XCode to appstoreconnect.apple.com and I can see that my latest version is under "processing". Since this is not a "new/fresh" app on appstoreconnect, it seems like it's not required to have a new screenshots and the app submission is instantly under processing status?

If I wish to update the screenshots, wondering if there is such option for me? Or is the option yet to be available due to the reason where it's still under "processing" status? And may I know usually how long is it gonna be under "processing" status?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to update the screenshots before submitting for review, as apple will need to review screenshots with every app update, if your App status is `processing for App Store` it means it got approved and you already released it and soon it will change to `Ready for Sale`. So you need to wait for next build submission and make sure to update screenshots before submitting for Review

**Note**:
The above is for app status, if the build is showing `processing`
 it means you just uploaded from xCode and it will take some time to be able to select that build, after that you will be able to update screenshots and release notes and finally submit for review

Comment: It's quite strange that if you saying **if your App status is processing for App Store it means it got approved ** because the moment I've submitted the app via xcode, the status is processing, it means apple immediately approves it?

Comment: I don't think there is a stage during submission called just `processing`, what i meant is `processing for App Store`, i am guessing that you are currently seeing processing in itunes connect attached to your build, this is completely different as once it is done you will be able to select that build and then prepare for submission, this means that you can update your screenshots as soon as you select that build and then you can submit for review

Comment: Sorry for double confirming as this is my first time going thru updating an app on appstore. I'm seeing it at appstoreconnect > activity > Build 1 (Processing) and App store Status is empty/blank. Is that normal?

Comment: No worries, Yeah that means you still didn't select the build to submit the new update, basically once the build processing is done you should be able to select it and update the screenshots and release note after that you will submit for review

Answer (score 2):

PSA: Since late 2021, Apple has allowed us to update App Store screenshots and video previews without submitting a new build. See it step-by-step here: https://www.roger.ml/p/app-store-screenshots